# $L_2$ bounds for $\zeta(1/2 + it)$ and a related integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Denote by $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function. I just learnt from this question  [$L_2$ bounds for tails of $\zeta(s)$ on a vertical line](https://mathoverflow.net/q/285197)

that $\int_{T}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(1/2 + it)}{1/4 + t^2}\mathrm{d}t=O(T^{-1}\log T)$ as $T\rightarrow +\infty$. But is the numerical value for the related integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(1/2 + it)}{1/4 + t^2} \mathrm{d}t $$ known?

Comment: Why should this integral converge?

Comment: $\frac{\zeta(s)}{s} = \frac{1}{s-1}-\int_1^\infty (x-\lfloor x \rfloor) x^{-s-1}dx$ and $\frac{\zeta(s+1)}{s} = \frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{\gamma}{s} -\int_0^\infty (\sum_{n \le x}\frac{1}{n} - \log(x)+\gamma) x^{-s-1}dx$ thus $F(t)=\zeta(1/2+it)(\frac{1}{1/2+it}+\frac{1}{1-(1/2+it)})-\frac{1}{1/2+it-1}+\frac{1}{(1/2+it-1)^2}-\frac{\gamma}{1/2+it-1}$ is the Fourier transform of $f(u)=(e^u-\lfloor e^u \rfloor) e^{-u/2}-(\sum_{n \le e^u} \frac{1}{n}+u-\gamma)e^{u/2}$ whence $\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{-T}^T F(t)dt = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f(u)+f(-u)}{2}$

Comment: @reuns, thanks. So it seems to me that $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(u)+f(-u)}{2}=0$, isn't it ?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao, i think the integral should converge since $\zeta(1/2 + it)=o(t)$.

Comment: No because $f(u)$ is supported on $u > 0$ (the $u < 0$ part is in the poles I substracted from $\frac{\zeta(1/2+it)}{t^2+1/4}$)

Comment: @acc10 You are right, in fact the best known bound (as far as I am aware) for $|\zeta(1/2 + it)|$ is found here: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2017-30-01/S0894-0347-2016-00860-3/

Answer (score 2):

For $\Re(s) > 1$, $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{s} = \int_1^\infty (\sum_{1 \le  n \le x} 1) x^{-s-1}dx, \qquad \frac{\zeta(s)}{s-1} = \int_1^\infty (x\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac1n) x^{-s-1}dx$$ Thus for $\Re(s) \in (0,1)$ $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}+\frac{\zeta(s)}{1-s}= \int_0^\infty ((\sum_{1 \le n \le x} 1-x)-x(\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \frac1n-\log x-\gamma)) x^{-s-1}dx$$

So that $\frac{\zeta(1/2+it)}{1/4+t^2}$ is the Fourier transform of $$g(u) = ((\sum_{1 \le n \le e^u} 1)-e^u-e^u(\sum_{1 \le n \le e^u} \frac1n) + e^u u+e^u\gamma)e^{-u/2}$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\zeta(1/2+it)}{1/4+t^2} dt = 2\pi\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{g(u)+g(-u)}{2}=2\pi( \gamma-1)$$

The integral converges absolutely [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_hypothesis) $\zeta(1/2+it) = O(t^c),c < 1$, and for the same reason you can shift the contour to $1/2+i(-\infty,+\infty)$ to $+\infty+i(-\infty,+\infty)$) and evaluate the integral as $-2 \pi \text{Res}(\frac{\zeta(s)}{s(1-s)},1)$.

Comment: In fact one can take $c = 13/84 + \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$, by this paper of Bourgain: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2017-30-01/S0894-0347-2016-00860-3/